# How to select all future closing times?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are trying to calculate store closing times based upon their opening hours.

We have a data model like the following for each store.

| id | weekday | opening_minute | shift_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 540 | 990 |
| 2 | 1 | 540 | 990 |
| 3 | 2 | 540 | 990 |
| 4 | 3 | 540 | 990 |
| 5 | 4 | 540 | 990 |
| 6 | 5 | 540 | 990 |
| 7 | 6 | 540 | 990 |

- `weekday` is the day of the week, where 0 is Sunday.
- `opening_minute` is the opening time where 540 is 09:00.
- `shift_length` is the length of time that the store is open, where 990 is
  16.5 hours.

There are some complexities here when it comes to calculating future closing
times.

We have tried the following SQL statement.

```sql
SELECT
  "opening_hours".*,
  date_trunc('week', '2021-04-29'::date - 1)::timestamp +
  make_interval(
    days => weekday,
    mins => opening_minute + shift_length
  ) closes_at
FROM "opening_hours";
```

This statement gets us halfway there, and the output is as follows.

| id | weekday | opening_minute | shift_length | closes_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 540 | 990 | `2021-04-28 01:30:00` |
| 2 | 1 | 540 | 990 | `2021-04-29 01:30:00` |
| 3 | 2 | 540 | 990 | `2021-04-30 01:30:00` |
| 4 | 3 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-01 01:30:00` |
| 5 | 4 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-02 01:30:00` |
| 6 | 5 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-03 01:30:00` |
| 7 | 6 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-04 01:30:00` |

We are making progress, but the output includes closing times for days in the
past. We want the output only to include future closing times.

We've been going round and round in circles with this. How can we output only
the future closing times? For example, if it is 08:30 on 29 April 2021, we would
expect the following output.

| id | weekday | opening_minute | shift_length | closes_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 540 | 990 | `2021-04-30 01:30:00` |
| 4 | 3 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-01 01:30:00` |
| 5 | 4 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-02 01:30:00` |
| 6 | 5 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-03 01:30:00` |
| 7 | 6 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-04 01:30:00` |
| 1 | 0 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-05 01:30:00` |
| 2 | 1 | 540 | 990 | `2021-05-06 01:30:00` |

Comment: Please show what output you want.  Do you only want "between now and the end of the week"?  Do you want between "now and the next 7 days"?

Comment: 990 minutes is 16 1/2 hours, not 14 1/2.

Comment: Add following `WHERE` clause?: `WHERE weekday >= date_part('dow', current_date)`.

Comment: @MatBailie, I have added the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to generate dates you want to calculate closing times for and then simply JOIN `opening_hours` to their "day of week" number:

```
SELECT 
  *
  , day.date + (opening_minute + shift_length) * ('1 minute')::interval as closes_at
FROM 
  (SELECT '2021-04-30'::date + generate_series(0, 6) as date)  as day
  JOIN opening_hours ON date_part('dow', day.date) = opening_hours.weekday
ORDER BY 
  closes_at
```

You can check it in [db<>fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bca4b9d2b6a2744847697987a1b993f8)

In stead of '2021-04-30' you can pass any date you want to generate next 7 closing times.

If you want 7 closing times from now that are strictly in the future, you should generate 8 dates (as closing time of current_date might already be in the past) then filter and display first 7 results:

```
SELECT 
  *
  , day.date + (opening_minute + shift_length) * ('1 minute')::interval as closes_at
FROM 
  (SELECT current_date + generate_series(0, 7) as date)  as day
  JOIN opening_hours ON date_part('dow', day.date) = opening_hours.weekday
WHERE
  day.date + (opening_minute + shift_length) * ('1 minute')::interval > now()
ORDER BY 
  closes_at
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem adding a Where clause saying

Where (repeat complex closing calc) > LOCALTIMESTAMP

, assuming your date times in the calculation are not encumbered with time zone problems.